# Using the Eclipse remote debugger throws com.sun.jdi.InternalException

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

The following error is being thrown:

```
com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Got error code in reply:35 occurred while retrieving value. for all expressions
```

I am getting this error for all expressions and cant find anything on it.  My guess is that the debugger isn't correctly connecting to the remote version, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 28):

It looks like the problem is related to the new debug feature "Show method result after a step operation":
See the thread [Eclipse Oxygen - Debugging Issue](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1088650&goto=1772065&) on the Eclipse forum:

**The workaround is to go to
Preferences -> Java -> Debug and disable the option
"Show method result after a step operation (if supported by the VM; may be slow)".**

See also the bug report in the Eclipse Bugzilla [Bug 531706 - Oygen.2 com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Got error code in reply:35 while debugging](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531706)

Comment: Save my day, nice finding.

Answer (score 6):

I have also faced with same issue on local server.
But, it was the issue of `for` loop.
I was using:

```
for(Object obj: list)
{
    for(Object obj2 : list)
    {}
}
```

When I replaced that code by simple for loop (index based), it resolved the above issue.
I think for each loop not able to iterate another list of same Type in same loop.
Work around for this is replace that for loop to index based for loop.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the "Logical Structures" turned on in the Expressions tab while debugging, this seems to still cause issues even in Eclipse IDE version 4.11.0. Turning it off helped me. It is not a "solution" *per se* rather a work-a-around.

See the [Eclipse Bug 48815](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=48815)

Comment: +1 for this answer.  I turned off Logical Structures & the debugger issue went away. 
 This is also described here - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537399

Comment: Turn off 'Logical Structures' for Expressions tab as well Variables tab. Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be sure: are you remote debugging some instrumented code ?

Because there seem to be some problems with [JProfiler](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5276797)...

Comment: Yeah. The same I got when debug code been instrumented by EMMA

Answer (score 4):

### Work-around: Uncheck this box:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I have got this plenty of times. It comes when I debug the application, and I think it occurs when the debugger tries to wrap a exception which arises due to code. At one instance while debugging when I see the logs I get some business exception, but while debugging it gave me `com.sun.jdi.internalexception`.

Yes I do remote debugging the servers JVM so it could also be beacuse the debugger isn't correctly connecting to the remote version as you pointed out

Comment: I got this value recently and it happened when I changed a variable to null to remote debug a NPE. Is there any resolution for this