# Eclipse: Debugging & inspection of variables causes com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I debug my program and add here and there a breakpoint. After a stop I want to inspect some of the variables and get sometimes a `com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException`. After searching in different sources I figured out that most likely the object was **G**arbage **C**ollected. Clicking here and there I could retrieve my object by nevertheless in the `Variables` view I cannot inspect the variable.

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms512m
-Xmx4096m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

I'm running under Linux/OpenSuSe with OpenJDK 1.8.0_151. Any hints how to avoid that kind of GC problems? Is this some kind of setting in the IDE?

Comment: If the object was garbage collected you are inspecting it at the wrong place, the object is alive before that breakpoint.

Comment: Yeah, but after a while keeping the editor open the object cannot be inspected any further. Therefore I assume its GCed

Comment: Try this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49003027/2733353

Answer (score 25):

Right click the variable, then click "Show Logical Structure", uncheck any collection.

Comment: Works for me but I don't understand why?

Comment: Note: The variable that you right click must be a collection and not an Object.

Answer (score 13):

While execution of your code is stopped at a breakpoint:

1. Right-click the variable in the `Variables` pane
2. Clicking on the collections (such as the Array in the image below) will uncheck them
3. Now you can inspect the variable

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed in Eclipse 4.18

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.18/jdt.php

> Stabilized logical structures in Variables view with active GC
>
> The Debug view no longer breaks when logical structures are shown while the application's garbage collector is active (com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException occurred while retrieving value).

Comment: bug still present in R-2023-12

Answer (score 0):

Instead of turning off logical structure, you can add a logical structure formatter, as detailed in this answer: [Eclipse debug mode view instance variable values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880396/eclipse-debug-mode-view-instance-variable-values/50881564#50881564). This prevents the exception and lets you see the variable in a useful way.