# Eclipse debug mode view instance variable values

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to view the instance variables values of the Arraylist in eclipse in debug mode but apart from the values in the list am unable to view variables like elementData or modCount that are part of the arraylist. I have tried using Watch, Display option as well but to no avail. Below is my screenshot after setting the breakpoint and triggering the program run:

[image]

Below is the screenshot that I found in one of the websites where the instance variables like elementData,modCount and size are visible:

[image]

Comment: Which Eclipse version are u using and what's the version in the mentioned site? May be they are not shown anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In oxygen, "Show Logical Structure" is [enabled by default](http://www.eclipse.org/oxygen/noteworthy/#show-logical-structure-enabled-by-default). All you have to do is click on it to disable it.

[image]

[Image taken from eclipse.org]

Answer (score 4):

In the current version (Oxygen.3) the default formatter for `Collection` shows only the members of the collection as an array.  I'm not sure when the more detailed formatter was removed, but you can easily create a logical structure formatter.

Right click on the variable in the Variables tab and select `Show Logical Structure/Edit Logical Structure`

[image]

Your view will have the `Collection` entry hilighted, and won't contain the `ArrayList` entry I just created.

Add a new entry:

[image]

Provide the class name you want to format, and a description. Select `List of Variables` and then add the variables you want to display, providing a code snippet for each one.  The code snippet executes as a method of the class.

[image]

End result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In some instances that I cannot view variables, like in your case, I would suggest using Expression tab and add new expression. To load expression tab on Eclipse IDE, click on Window > Show View > Expression. Set breakpoint, hit debug, then expression tab should load `arrNames` and you can expand to view properties and data.

[image: Expression Tab]

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Window->show view->expressions** then in Expressions window go to variables tab
there you will see your variables right click on any one of them you will see **Show logical structure.**
Untick the Array option from there and debug again you will see elementData,modCount and size varibles.[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQpl4.png)