# Eclipse debugging error : ObjectCollectedException occured while retrieving value

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

When I try to retrieve values from variable pannel in debugging mode, it shows error like the title above.
So I cannot see any values from the variables.

I've already tried unchecking as this site described. ([Eclipse: Debugging & inspection of variables causes com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004564/eclipse-debugging-inspection-of-variables-causes-com-sun-jdi-objectcollectede))
but still, it shows the same error.

please help me to solve this problems. Thank you!

Comment: Is this Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12) or an outdated version? I think there was a bug in an older version that has been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: It's outdated I think. It shows "2018-12" in its name.

Comment: Does [upgrading to 2019-06 (4.12)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades) fix your issue?