# Unable to debug Junit test anywhere

Tags: java, spring, junit, adoptopenjdk

I tried debugging a junit test in STS (Spring Tool Suite).

When I try to perform 'step-into' in any method of the class under test object I get

`com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Got error code in reply:35 occurred retrieving 'this' from stack frame`.

When I do the same in IntelliJ IDEA I get

`'this' is not available`.

I tried everything from [Using the Eclipse remote debugger throws com.sun.jdi.InternalException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295686/using-the-eclipse-remote-debugger-throws-com-sun-jdi-internalexception) but nothing turns out to be useful.

I installed java using

`brew cask install adoptopenjdk8`.

STS version is `4.7.0.RELEASE`

IntelliJ IDEA Version is `2020.1.2`

JUnit version is `4.13`

Comment: The information you provided is not enough to diagnose the problem. Please provide a [example].

Comment: see https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2082#issuecomment-854105872, If you set the breakpoint in the first line of the method, IntelliJ will got `'this' is not available`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after a lot of debugging and isolating all tools I found that the culprit was

`mock-maker-inline`

which I added in project's src/test/resources/mockito-extensions directory to mock final classes (ref: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final).

Please feel free to comment any better way where I don't have to add that line and still can mock final classes + won't get that exception.